# Deriving distribution under change of variables between spaces of unequal dimension

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function, transform

For a function of random variables $T:\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m$ [Wikipedia outlines how to handle three cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function):

- [$m = n = 1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar)
- [$m=n > 1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Vector_to_vector)
- [$n>1 \land m=1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Vector_to_scalar)

There seems to be two missing cases:

- $n < m$
- $n > m \land m > 1$

Give a function of random variables $T$ and a joint probability density function $f_{X_1, \cdots, X_n} (x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ both having suitable smoothness, and local invertibility for $T$, how do I derive the density of $T(X_1, \cdots, T_n)$ for these two remaining cases?

---

Henry in the comments raised an interesting point. It gave me some pause to think, which I appreciate. Would there still be a distribution in the case of $n < m$?

I think yes. Suppose we have $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and we are mapping $X \mapsto (\cos X, \sin X)$. The resulting points have to lay on the circle, which feels rather deterministic. But there will be uncertainty about where on the circle a sample of $X$ will map to. I think there will be some kind of density on (or should I say within?) the parametric object.

Here is a coded example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.normal(size=1000)

y1 = np.cos(x)
y2 = np.sin(x)
d = {'$\cos X$':y1, '$\sin X$':y2}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

sns.jointplot(data=df, x='$\cos X$', y='$\sin X$')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: With $n < m$, is there a density?

Comment: @Henry That is an excellent question. Consider the example $X \mapsto (\cos X, \sin X )$ with $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ will just be points precisely on a unit circle. There will be uncertainty about where the points will be on the circle, but not whether they are on the circle. I suspect a density **on the circle** might exist in this example.

Comment: But that would not be a density on $\mathbb R^2$.   Similarly $X \mapsto (X, X)$ would not have a density on  $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: @Henry I agree. In this example, $n=1 \land m =2$, could I just consider the density of $\cos X$ separately from $\sin X$? That is, derive the [scalar-to-scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar) density component-wise? Thus have a pair of densities corresponding to the components of the image?

Comment: I think not:  considering the components separately might suggest they were independent  when they clearly are highly dependent in that knowing the value of one restricts  the other to at most two possible values

Comment: @Henry I tend to agree with that as well. I feel like I am missing something. There's clearly a density-like behaviour in the computational example above, but defining a joint density on the circle in theory doesn't seem obvious either.

Comment: There exists a density for $T(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ wrt the proper measure, namely the [Hausdorff measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure) on the manifold $T(\mathbb R^n)$. For instance the Hausdorff measure on the circle in the example is the Uniform measure on the circle.

Comment: *(follow-up)* The alternative is to find an $n$-dimension reparameterisation of the $m$-dimension manifold in order to turn the transform bijective. In the case of the circle, the reparameterisation of choice is the polar one, which makes $T$ the identity transform.

Comment: @Xi'an I am looking at the [definition of Hausdorff measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure#Definition) and finding it unclear how to make use of it here.

Comment: This distribution on a circle reminds me of the notion of a [wrapped normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_distribution#Wrapped_normal_distribution).

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/3293e31ce0c9dfaee376d8a53b6c5edf) is a Python gist for above code/plot.