# Transforming one distribution into another with different support

Tags: probability, distributions, optimization, variational-bayes

Consider the following two random variables:

1. A random vector $S$ with law $h$ and support $\mathcal{S}$ and,
2. a random vector $X$ with law $c$ and support $\mathcal{X}$.

Assume

1. $\text{Dim}(\mathcal{S}) \geq \text{Dim}(\mathcal{X})$
2. $\mathcal{S}, \mathcal{X}$ are finite, and
3. $|\mathcal{S}| \geq |\mathcal{X}|$.

I want to find a surjective function $T: \mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{X}$ such that $c(x) = \sum_{s \in \tau_x} h(s)$ for all $x \in \mathcal{X}$ where $\tau_x = \{s: T(s) = x\}$.
If such a surjective function does not exist, I want to find the closest approximation, e.g., one that minimizes $\left (h(s) - \sum_{s \in \tau_x} h(s) \right )^2 $.

Is there a name for such a problem? Are there problems related or similar to this?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/589631/deriving-distribution-under-change-of-variables-between-spaces-of-unequal-dimens

Comment: What does your first condition mean? I understand $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{X}$ are just some finite sets. How is then "dimension" defined?

Comment: @gg dimension is the dimension of the random variable (vector). E.g., a realization of such a random vector might be (1,5,3,9), which has four dimensions.